# User registration to check if user exists based on email -- Custom UserStore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have created Custom UsersyStore and In `CreateAsync` Method it creates user.

I like to know how and where to check if user already exists based on email?

`CreateAsync` method returns just Task. But how I can check if user already exists. currently it creating new user based on Id

Answer (score 1):

You have to validate the user (and password) before creating it. Assuming the Identity Framework template, you can use something like this to validate the password and user:

```
var identityResult = await userManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(account.Password);
if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
    return SomeError(identityResult);

// Validate the new user BEFORE creating in the database.
identityResult = await userManager.UserValidator.ValidateAsync(appUser);
if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
    return SomeError(identityResult);

identityResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, account.Password);
if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
    return SomeError(identityResult);
```

You can set the validation options in:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

    // Configure validation logic for usernames
    manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
    };

    // ...
}
```

Please note that this will assume the username is the email. If you don't want this then you should set `RequireUniqueEmail = false`. But I think in that case it won't check for unique email. So you can add this line to check the unique email:

```
var isUniqueEmail = (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email) == null);
```